# How do I convert 1e-8 to 0.00000001 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I convert `1e-8` to `0.00000001` in JavaScript?

I'm using Angular and it does not like the short syntax when using `<input type="number">`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Numbers have a [`toFixed(digits)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method which will do this:

```
1e-8.toFixed(8);
```

If you've got a string, you first need to convert it to a number:

```
parseFloat('1e-8').toFixed(8);
```

Comment: It returns string, but if I want number without 'e'?